# jQuery content slider: Simplest

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to make the simplest content slider possible.  *I don't want a plugin...* I simply want an easy way to **slide** a couple of divs left and right based on next/previous buttons.

If I'm shooting myself in the foot, though, I'll just use a plugin. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I believe is to use the anaimate function on your elements:

```
$("#left").click(function(){
  $(".block").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
});
```

Look here for more info: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: What are the pros/cons of using this?  Rather, what am I limiting myself to by doing it this way?

Comment: Pros are that you know exactly how the code works because you did everything but the animation.  Also you can keep your code base smaller by not including plugins, though that's not much of an advantage.  Cons are you have to do everything yourself, so you're kind of re-creating the wheel and wasting time.

Comment: Here's another question...  Could you show html/css.  I'm currently trying to create this, and I’m stuck getting the divs to float left and overflow outside my .content-wrapper div...

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for, but if you want the element to show when it moves outside an element use 'overflow:visible;' in the style of that parent element.

Comment: Welp, I've realized that it's way too much of a hassle to do this manually.  Thanks!